# About React,Restful and web server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, web-services, restify

I have a local server like 55.5.555.555. First I made a Login WebUI by using React, My code under

```
class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      un : "",
      pwd : "",
    };
}
render() {
  return (
   <div>

     <input type="text" />
     <input type= "password"/>
     <button type='submit'>Submit</button>  
</div>
  );
}}
export default Login;
```

How should I post my username and password to 55.5.555.555,I had tried 3 methods but never success,

Comment: How are you submitting the values ? use `onChange` for username and pwd and form submit using 'onSubmit`.

Comment: Please show your code, which used for sending data to server